# How to disable other buttons onclick for a short period of time

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

i have simple quizz project where i fetch data of questions and answers my problem is when i click on one of the answers i want other buttons to be disabled because if someone keeps pressing on other options the quiz will rapidly change questions. i want to disable other answer options when i clik on the  answer and then after the next question generates enable them again and so on

```
import './App.css';
import axios from 'axios'
import {useState,useEffect} from 'react'

function App() {
  const [quiz,setQuiz] = useState([])
  const [answer,setAnswer] = useState([])
  const [correct,setCorrect] =useState('')
  const [points,setPoints] = useState(0)
  const [turns,setTurns] = useState(0)
  const [disabled,setDisabled] = useState(false)

  function refreshPage() {
    window.location.reload(false);
  }

  useEffect(()=>{
    axios.get('https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=10')
    .then(res =>{
       setQuiz(res.data.results[0])
       let tempVar = res.data.results[0] ;
       setAnswer([...tempVar.incorrect_answers,tempVar.correct_answer].sort(()=>Math.random() - 0.5))
      setCorrect(tempVar.correct_answer)
      console.log(res.data)
      console.log(answer)
       
    
    })
    .catch(err=>{
      console.log(err);
    })
  },[])

  const  handleClick = (e) =>{
    setDisabled(true)
    if(disabled && e.target.innerText === correct){
     
      setPoints(points + 1)
      setTurns(turns + 1)
      e.target.style.background = 'green'
      setTimeout(() => e.target.style.background = '', 2000);  
   
      setTimeout(() => {
        axios.get('https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=10')
        .then(res=>{
           setQuiz(res.data.results[0])
           let tempVar = res.data.results[0] ;
           setAnswer([...tempVar.incorrect_answers,tempVar.correct_answer].sort(()=>Math.random() - 0.5))
          setCorrect(tempVar.correct_answer)
      })
      .catch(err=>{
        console.log(err);
      })
    }, 2000);
    console.log(points)
    } else if(e.target.innerText !== correct){
      setTurns(turns + 1)
      e.target.style.background = 'red'
     setTimeout(() => e.target.style.background='', 2000);

      setTimeout(() => {
        axios.get('https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=10')
        .then(res=>{
           setQuiz(res.data.results[0])
           let tempVar = res.data.results[0] ;
           setAnswer([...tempVar.incorrect_answers,tempVar.correct_answer].sort(()=>Math.random() - 0.5))
          setCorrect(tempVar.correct_answer)
      })
      .catch(err=>{
        console.log(err);
      })
    }, 2000);
    } 
    }
    
if(points >= 10|| turns >= 10){
  return (
    <div className='score'>
      <h1>Well done !</h1>
     <p>Your Score: {points}</p>
      <button className='button-28' onClick={refreshPage}>New Test</button>
    </div>
  )
}

  return (
    <div className="App">
     <div className='grid'>
   <h1>{quiz.question}</h1>
   { answer?.map(answers =>
   <button className='button-28' onClick={handleClick}key={answers}>{answers}</button>
   )
   }

    </div>
    </div>

  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Setting state is async. Calling `setDisabled(true)` then immediately checking `disabled`, besides not making sense at all, won't work as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update your `disabled` state after you update your answers and correct. And use that state as `disabled = true/false` in your buttons

```
import './App.css';
import axios from 'axios'
import {useState,useEffect} from 'react'

function App() {
  const [quiz,setQuiz] = useState([])
  const [answer,setAnswer] = useState([])
  const [correct,setCorrect] =useState('')
  const [points,setPoints] = useState(0)
  const [turns,setTurns] = useState(0)
  const [disabled,setDisabled] = useState(false)

  function refreshPage() {
    window.location.reload(false);
  }

  useEffect(()=>{
    axios.get('https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=10')
    .then(res =>{
       setQuiz(res.data.results[0])
       let tempVar = res.data.results[0] ;
       setAnswer([...tempVar.incorrect_answers,tempVar.correct_answer].sort(()=>Math.random() - 0.5))
      setCorrect(tempVar.correct_answer)
      console.log(res.data)
      console.log(answer)
       
    
    })
    .catch(err=>{
      console.log(err);
    })
  },[])

  const  handleClick = (e) =>{
    setDisabled(true)
    if(disabled && e.target.innerText === correct){
     
      setPoints(points + 1)
      setTurns(turns + 1)
      e.target.style.background = 'green'
      setTimeout(() => e.target.style.background = '', 2000);  
   
      setTimeout(() => {
        axios.get('https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=10')
        .then(res=>{
           setQuiz(res.data.results[0])
           let tempVar = res.data.results[0] ;
           setAnswer([...tempVar.incorrect_answers,tempVar.correct_answer].sort(()=>Math.random() - 0.5))
          setCorrect(tempVar.correct_answer)
          setDisabled(false)
      })
      .catch(err=>{
        console.log(err);
        setDisabled(false)
      })
    }, 2000);
    console.log(points)
    } else if(e.target.innerText !== correct){
      setTurns(turns + 1)
      e.target.style.background = 'red'
     setTimeout(() => e.target.style.background='', 2000);

      setTimeout(() => {
        axios.get('https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=10')
        .then(res=>{
           setQuiz(res.data.results[0])
           let tempVar = res.data.results[0] ;
           setAnswer([...tempVar.incorrect_answers,tempVar.correct_answer].sort(()=>Math.random() - 0.5))
          setCorrect(tempVar.correct_answer)
          setDisabled(false)
      })
      .catch(err=>{
        console.log(err);
        setDisabled(false)
      })
    }, 2000);
    } 
    }
    
if(points >= 10|| turns >= 10){
  return (
    <div className='score'>
      <h1>Well done !</h1>
     <p>Your Score: {points}</p>
      <button className='button-28' onClick={refreshPage}>New Test</button>
    </div>
  )
}

  return (
    <div className="App">
     <div className='grid'>
   <h1>{quiz.question}</h1>
   { answer?.map(answers =>
   <button className='button-28' onClick={handleClick}key={answers} disabled={disabled}>{answers}</button>
   )
   }

    </div>
    </div>

  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: thank you this worked. can u explain how this works without checking the disabled state ?

Comment: Well you dont have to check the `disabled` state. Set it to true then you want and react will render the disabled buttons, which you are doing when you click the button. But when you get your answers and correct from the API set them back to false.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can achieve what you wanted, I tried to do in your code
I added a state for tracking user's selected answer and that way you can disable other answers.

```
import "./styles.css";
import axios from "axios";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function App() {
  const [quiz, setQuiz] = useState([]);
  const [answer, setAnswer] = useState([]);
  const [correct, setCorrect] = useState("");
  const [selectedAnswer, setSelectedAnswer] = useState("");
  const [points, setPoints] = useState(0);
  const [turns, setTurns] = useState(0);
  const [disabled, setDisabled] = useState(false);

  function refreshPage() {
    window.location.reload(false);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=10")
      .then((res) => {
        setQuiz(res.data.results[0]);
        let tempVar = res.data.results[0];
        setAnswer(
          [...tempVar.incorrect_answers, tempVar.correct_answer].sort(
            () => Math.random() - 0.5
          )
        );
        setCorrect(tempVar.correct_answer);
        console.log(res.data);
        console.log(answer);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }, []);

  const handleClick = (userAnswer) => (e) => {
    setSelectedAnswer(userAnswer);
    setDisabled(true);
    if (disabled && e.target.innerText === correct) {
      setPoints(points + 1);
      setTurns(turns + 1);
      e.target.style.background = "green";
      setTimeout(() => (e.target.style.background = ""), 2000);

      setTimeout(() => {
        axios
          .get("https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=10")
          .then((res) => {
            setQuiz(res.data.results[0]);
            let tempVar = res.data.results[0];
            setAnswer(
              [...tempVar.incorrect_answers, tempVar.correct_answer].sort(
                () => Math.random() - 0.5
              )
            );
            setCorrect(tempVar.correct_answer);
            setSelectedAnswer("");
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
          });
      }, 2000);
      console.log(points);
    } else if (e.target.innerText !== correct) {
      setTurns(turns + 1);
      e.target.style.background = "red";
      setTimeout(() => (e.target.style.background = ""), 2000);

      setTimeout(() => {
        axios
          .get("https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=10")
          .then((res) => {
            setQuiz(res.data.results[0]);
            let tempVar = res.data.results[0];
            setAnswer(
              [...tempVar.incorrect_answers, tempVar.correct_answer].sort(
                () => Math.random() - 0.5
              )
            );
            setCorrect(tempVar.correct_answer);
            setSelectedAnswer("");
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
          });
      }, 2000);
    }
  };

  if (points >= 10 || turns >= 10) {
    return (
      <div className="score">
        <h1>Well done !</h1>
        <p>Your Score: {points}</p>
        <button className="button-28" onClick={refreshPage}>
          New Test
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="grid">
        <h1>{quiz.question}</h1>
        {answer?.map((answers) => (
          <button
            disabled={selectedAnswer && answers !== selectedAnswer}
            className="button-28"
            onClick={handleClick(answers)}
            key={answers}
          >
            {answers}
          </button>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)

const getDate = async () => {
   setLoading(true)
   const data = await axios.get('/teste')
   ...
   setLoading(false)
}

<button disabled={loading}>Teste</button>
```

Comment: where should i implement that ?